# IE7 Floating ULs not displaying

Tags: html, css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

I'm having some trouble getting floating

elements to display in a  element in ie7. I have managed to get them to show in IE6, but no dice with IE7. I'm also having trouble getting a floated image element and div to show. Here is the site link:

[link text](http://tedxconejo.elliottmediagroup.com)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="http://tedxconejo.elliottmediagroup.com"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/tedxlogo_transparent.png" alt="TedxConejo" id="logo"/></a>
        <p id="headertext">what's the big idea?<br/><span id='date'>03/26/11</span></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
        </ul>

        <div class="clear"></div>



    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
img#logo   {width: 340px; height: 72px; float: left; margin-bottom: 15px}    
ul#nav li  {min-width: 60px; min-height: 10px;  display: block; float: left; margin-right: 60px; text-transform: lowercase; z-index: 100001}
ul#nav li:last-child, ul#nav li:last-child a    {float: right; background-color: #ff2b06; color: #ffffff; margin-right: 0px;}
ul#nav li a  {text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px; color: #333333; display: inline;  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;z-index: 100001}
ul#nav li a.current, ul#nav li a:hover  {background: #ff2B06; color: #ffffff}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in the css

`#header>a { 
float:left
}`